# create a vue component using another page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to load divs from page 2 into page 1 with VueJs.

localhost/getnew

```
<html>
<head>
<title> title </title>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="content2"> this is content2</div>
<div id="content3"> this is content3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get and use the id content2 from getnew to create a div into home with the content of that div, after the link was clicked and deleted, and do the same with content3, content4 and successively.

localhost/homepage

```
<html>
<head>
<title> title </title>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="content1"> this is content1</div>
<a href="#"> get content</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then would be like that.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> title </title>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="content1"> this is content1</div>
<div>this is content2</div>
<div>this is content3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new in VueJs and I have no idea how to do that. If someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: You could make components for the `content1` as well as the `content2` and `content3` divs, and include them on both pages.

Answer (score 2):

In Vue, like in most SPA's, the page (DOM) doesn't hold data.
The page is a rendering tool which displays data held in the source. The source can be:

- local data, kept in `vm.data()` (typically holding specific data for current component - it can be passed down to child components, though)
- global data, held in a specialized module for holding data and managing state, passed to vm through computed (getters).
  This specialized data module is called [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).
  You interact with it dispatching actions, which commit mutations to [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) state.
  Any component, on any page, listening to the the Vuex data will be updated automatically on any change, regardless of which component triggered the mutation.

---

If your data is not overly complex, you might be able to manage it without Vuex, using a [simple state management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) pattern.

---

So, in a nutshell, you don't get the div with some `#id` from one page to another. You just mutate the store and then everywhere that data is used it updates.